# Can you install a wall ontop of a travertine floor?

Tags: construction, travertine

Can you install a 2x4 wall that is 13' long on top of a travertine tile floor? Or do I need to cut the tile and mount the bottom stud right to the cement? This will not be a load bearing wall.

Comment: You certainly can. You may really annoy the next owner that decides to remove the tile, but that's their problem. :)

Comment: Do you mount it right to it? As in drill through it?

Comment: You can drill, or use a powder-actuated gun to drive nails in. The latter is more fun.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert but I am going to put an 8 foot high pantry wall on top of an oak wood floor. I don't expect to have any problem. I have no idea if it meets code. In the case of travertine this is what I think:

It depends on the load you expect and what your floor is made of. Since your floor is concrete it should work but you still need to drill through the tile to make an attachment to the concrete. Oversize the hole through the tile only. You may still get cracks from the drilling. I would also think it is a good idea to put some adhesive underneath the walls bottom plate to even out the tile/joint irregularities and reduce the stress on tile high spots. Keep in mind if you decide to cut the tile you might still get stress fractures in the tile from the cutting process. You can easily cover up any small cracks that run the length of the wall with molding. If it were me I would do it, but like I stated earlier I am no expert.

on the [finehomebuilding forum they seem to agree](http://forums.finehomebuilding.com/breaktime/construction-techniques/can-i-frame-stud-wall-top-ceramic-tile-floor).